# Connecting to MySQL database on Google Cloud Storage from IPv6

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am at a location that has an IPv6 rather than IPv4 (this is becoming more common) and I cannot connect. I'm going to Storage->SQL->AccessControl just like I would with an IPv4, clicking "Add Item" and putting the address under "Network". I haven't had any issues with enabling IPv4 that way, but haven't succeeded with IPv6 in any of several locations I've tried. Am I missing something??

Thanks.

Comment: Are you connecting to the IPv6 address you're automatically assigned, rather than the IPv4 address?

Comment: I'm connecting to the IPv4 address. I just want to allow connection from a specific IPv6 address.

Comment: Why are you not connecting to the IPv6 address of the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not support IPv6 addresses so far.

Comment: @Army-L Is there a timeline for when IPv6 addresses will be supported?

Comment: @wogsland Sorry, I have no idea on the timeline.